Deleting video files from gallery not working on Android 14
I am trying to make a function that deletes a selected video from a recycler view. After the confirmation in the confirmDeleteDialog I receive "Failed to delete video" , knowing that the same code was working fine in the same device before adding the "READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" and the "READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED" permissions in the manifest .
Below is the delete function, the function used to get the videos and the manifest file :
 binding.deleteVideoButton.setOnClickListener {
            //check this section there is something wrong with it
            val file = File(currentVideoUri.path.toString())
            if (file.exists() && !lock) {
                Utilities.moveViewUpAndBack(binding.deleteVideoButton)

                val confirmDeleteDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.delete_video))
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.deletion_confirmation))
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes)) { _, _ ->
                        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                            val deleted = file.delete()
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                                if (deleted) {
                                    val tempoVideos = Utilities.listVideos(applicationContext)
                                    val tempoThumbnails = Utilities.convertFilesToBitmaps(tempoVideos.take(5))
                                    val tempoUris = tempoVideos.map { Uri.fromFile(it) }
                                    if (tempoUris.isNotEmpty()) {
                                        currentVideoUri = tempoUris[0]
                                        preparePlayer(currentVideoUri)
                                    }
                                    adapter.updateThumbnails(tempoThumbnails, tempoUris)
                                    loadRemainingBitmaps(tempoVideos.drop(5))
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(this@PreviewActivity,
                                        getString(R.string.failed_to_delete_video),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                                //alertDialog.dismiss()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), null)
                    .create()
                confirmDeleteDialog.show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.file_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

listVideos() function
   fun listVideos(context: Context): List<File> {
            val videos = mutableListOf<File>()
            val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)

            val selection =
                "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} LIKE ? AND ${MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} NOT LIKE ? AND ${MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} LIKE ?"
            val selectionArgs = arrayOf("%camerago_%", "%.pending%", "%.mp4")

            val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED} DESC"

            val query = context.contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                sortOrder)
            query?.use { cursor ->
                val nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val data = cursor.getString(dataColumn)
                    //Log.e("logo", "video name: $name")
                    videos.add(File(data))
                }
            }
            return videos
        }

Manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE" />


    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <!--implementation of a file provider in order to be able to share the video to other platforms-->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.nerovero.camerago.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <!--check whether enabled attribute is necessary in the service or not   -->
        <service
            android:name=".VideoRecordingService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="camera|microphone"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true" >

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>

I tried the contentResolver method but it does not work as well.

There is a bit of a disconnect in your code. You are building a List<File>, but your delete logic is working with currentVideoUri, which appears to be a Uri.
Regardless, the reason you cannot delete the video is simple: at best, you only have read access. There is no means for you to delete an arbitrary file that you get by querying the MediaStore and using its unreliable DATA column. The only files that you can delete are ones that your app created, and then only in select locations IIRC.

@CommonsWare this code works very well on version lower than Android 14. means that the Android 14 has some restrictions regarding accessing the media. If you don't mind can you share with us the right way or maybe a reference to how  to delete files created by an app in SDK 34 ?

Use the Storage Access Framework, such as ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument, and let the user choose the content that way. Wrap the Uri that you get back in DocumentFile.fromSingleUri() to get a DocumentFile. Then, call delete() on the DocumentFile. "created by an app" -- if these files are created by your own app installation (i.e., not a previous installation that was uninstalled then reinstalled), then the issue might be tied to where you are writing them.

@CommonsWare believe it or not the code now working very well and I am able to delete my videos from within the app activity . All I did was just add a sharedPreference  in An activity and a service to detect when a video recording is done in the Foreground ( which is not related to the Storage access at all) .
